# BInd "Super (Win) Key" release event (not press) in XFCE 4.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce

The heading says it all. In short I want to have the behavior as in *gnome-shell* : when I release the super key, the overview is triggered. With xfce, I want it to trigger the main menu.

I have the whisker plugin installed, so its just the matter to selecting `xfce4-popup-whiskermenu` as the command for the shortcut, but the problem I am facing is that simply selecting Super key binds it to "press" event rather than release, which is not what I want.

There doesnt seem to be a way to do it via the settings manager GUI. Is there a way to edit xfce configuration files to achieve this ?

Comment: Hello, same problem here. Did you find a solution since then?